# Python method for calculating conditional means and variances?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statsmodels

Is there a standard way in Python to calculate the *conditional* means and variances of pandas DataFrame variables? The aim is to test the data for over or under dispersion as a prerequisite for assessing whether a Poisson or Negative Binomial model is most suitable for regression.

Scanning around the R ecosystem and Cross Validated, I think R has some packages with built-in parameter dispersion methods. But I can't find a Python equivalent in pandas, SciPy or StatsModels.

This is the head of the data I'm working with. There are 25,000 observations.

```
aspunet c_#     c_++    Ruby    java
0       0       0       0       6
11      0       0       0       0
0       0       7       0       0
0       0       0       9       0   
8       0       0       0       0
0       2       0       0       0
0       0       0       4       0   
0       0       0       0       6
```

Comment: The Poisson regression **is** calculating the conditional mean, even when there is overdispersion. You could test for overdispersion based on the Poisson estimate. However, with the large number of observations and not too many regressors, I don't see a reason why not to use NegativeBinomial right away instead of pretesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
conditional = [df.groupby(col_name) for col_name in df.columns]
mean        = [cond.mean() for cond in conditional]
var         = [cond.var() for cond in conditional]
```

Comment: What output do you get from this? I get ten of these `<zip at 0x10f313dc8>`

Comment: I wonder if this method gives the same result than: var(Y|X=x) = sum((y-mean(Y|X=x))^2) ?